# "Error: expected identifier or '(' before 'float'" when compiling C program

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand (and 'translate' to Python) the C program at https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/code/pole.c, which simulates reinforcement learning of a cart-pole system.

One of the adaptations I'm trying to make is to move the `pole.h` header file into `pole.c`. However, when I try to compile using `gcc pole3.c -lm` (where `pole3.c` is what I named the edited program), I get the following two errors:

```
pole3.c:46:35: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘float’
 #define random                  ((float) rand() / (float)((1 << 31) - 1))
                                   ^
pole3.c:46:42: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘rand’
 #define random                  ((float) rand() / (float)((1 << 31) - 1))
```

Why are these errors occurring? (The original `pole.c` compiles, and as I understand it, including a header file is the same as copy-pasting it into the source code).

For reference, here is the (attempted) program `pole3.c`:

```
/* Parameters for reinforcement algorithm.  */

#define min(x, y)               ((x <= y) ? x : y)
#define max(x, y)           ((x >= y) ? x : y)
#define prob_push_right(s)      (1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-max(-50.0, min(s, 50.0)))))
#define random                  ((float) rand() / (float)((1 << 31) - 1))

#define N_BOXES         162         /* Number of disjoint boxes of state space. */
#define ALPHA       1000        /* Learning rate for action weights, w. */
#define BETA        0.5         /* Learning rate for critic weights, v. */
#define GAMMA       0.95        /* Discount factor for critic. */
#define LAMBDAw     0.9         /* Decay rate for w eligibility trace. */
#define LAMBDAv     0.8         /* Decay rate for v eligibility trace. */

#define MAX_FAILURES     300         /* Termination criterion. */
#define MAX_STEPS        100000

#define RUNS 1


/*** Parameters for simulation ***/

#define GRAVITY 9.8
#define MASSCART 1.0
#define MASSPOLE 0.1
#define TOTAL_MASS (MASSPOLE + MASSCART)
#define LENGTH 0.5        /* actually half the pole's length */
#define POLEMASS_LENGTH (MASSPOLE * LENGTH)
#define FORCE_MAG 10.0
#define TAU 0.02          /* seconds between state updates */
#define FOURTHIRDS 1.3333333333333

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
// #include "pole.h"


typedef float vector[N_BOXES];

int main()
{
  int i,seed;

  // printf("enter seed:");
  // scanf("%d",&seed);
  // srand(seed);

  seed = 5;
  srand(seed);

  for (i=0; i<RUNS; i++)
    run_trial(i);

  return 0;

}

run_trial(run)
int run;
{
  float x,          /* cart position, meters */
        x_dot,          /* cart velocity */
        theta,          /* pole angle, radians */
        theta_dot;      /* pole angular velocity */
  vector  w,            /* vector of action weights */
          v,            /* vector of critic weights */
          e,            /* vector of action weight eligibilities */
          xbar;         /* vector of critic weight eligibilities */
  float p, oldp, rhat, r;
  int tsteps=0,box, i,y, steps = 0, failures=0, failed;

  /*--- Initialize action and heuristic critic weights and traces. ---*/
  for (i = 0; i < N_BOXES; i++)
    w[i] = v[i] = xbar[i] = e[i] = 0.0;

  /*--- Starting state is (0 0 0 0) ---*/
  x = x_dot = theta = theta_dot = 0.0;

  /*--- Find box in state space containing start state ---*/
  box = get_box(x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot);

  /*--- Iterate through the action-learn loop. ---*/
  while (steps++ < MAX_STEPS && failures < MAX_FAILURES)
    {
      /*--- Choose action randomly, biased by current weight. ---*/
      y = (random < prob_push_right(w[box]));

      tsteps++;  /* total number of steps */

      /*--- Update traces. ---*/
      e[box] += (1.0 - LAMBDAw) * (y - 0.5);
      xbar[box] += (1.0 - LAMBDAv);

      /*--- Remember prediction of failure for current state ---*/
      oldp = v[box];

      /*--- Apply action to the simulated cart-pole ---*/
      cart_pole(y, &x, &x_dot, &theta, &theta_dot);

      /*--- Get box of state space containing the resulting state. ---*/
      box = get_box(x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot);

      if (box < 0)
    {
      /*--- Failure occurred. ---*/
      failed = 1;
      failures++;
      printf("Trial %d was %d steps.\n", failures, steps);
      steps = 0;

      /*--- Reset state to (0 0 0 0).  Find the box. ---*/
      x = x_dot = theta = theta_dot = 0.0;
      box = get_box(x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot);

      /*--- Reinforcement upon failure is -1. Prediction of failure is 0. ---*/
      r = -1.0;
      p = 0.;
    }
      else
    {
      /*--- Not a failure. ---*/
      failed = 0;

      /*--- Reinforcement is 0. Prediction of failure given by v weight. ---*/
      r = 0;
      p= v[box];
    }

      /*--- Heuristic reinforcement is:   current reinforcement
          + gamma * new failure prediction - previous failure prediction ---*/
      rhat = r + GAMMA * p - oldp;

      for (i = 0; i < N_BOXES; i++)
    {
      /*--- Update all weights. ---*/
      w[i] += ALPHA * rhat * e[i];
      v[i] += BETA * rhat * xbar[i];
      if (v[i] < -1.0)
        v[i] = v[i];

      if (failed)
        {
          /*--- If failure, zero all traces. ---*/
          e[i] = 0.;
          xbar[i] = 0.;
        }
      else
        {
          /*--- Otherwise, update (decay) the traces. ---*/
          e[i] *= LAMBDAw;
          xbar[i] *= LAMBDAv;
        }
    }

    }
  if (failures == MAX_FAILURES)
    printf("run:%d Pole not balanced. Stopping after %d trials and %d steps.",run,failures,tsteps);
  else
    printf("Run:%d Pole balanced successfully for at least %d steps after %d trials and %d steps\n", run,steps,failures,tsteps);
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------
   cart_pole:  Takes an action (0 or 1) and the current values of the
 four state variables and updates their values by estimating the state
 TAU seconds later.
----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

cart_pole(action, x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot)
int action;
float *x, *x_dot, *theta, *theta_dot;
{
    float xacc,thetaacc,force,costheta,sintheta,temp;

    force = (action>0)? FORCE_MAG : -FORCE_MAG;
    costheta = cos(*theta);
    sintheta = sin(*theta);

    temp = (force + POLEMASS_LENGTH * *theta_dot * *theta_dot * sintheta)
                 / TOTAL_MASS;

    thetaacc = (GRAVITY * sintheta - costheta* temp)
           / (LENGTH * (FOURTHIRDS - MASSPOLE * costheta * costheta
                                              / TOTAL_MASS));

    xacc  = temp - POLEMASS_LENGTH * thetaacc* costheta / TOTAL_MASS;

/*** Update the four state variables, using Euler's method. ***/

    *x  += TAU * *x_dot;
    *x_dot += TAU * xacc;
    *theta += TAU * *theta_dot;
    *theta_dot += TAU * thetaacc;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------
   get_box:  Given the current state, returns a number from 1 to 162
  designating the region of the state space encompassing the current state.
  Returns a value of -1 if a failure state is encountered.
----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#define one_degree 0.0174532    /* 2pi/360 */
#define six_degrees 0.1047192
#define twelve_degrees 0.2094384
#define fifty_degrees 0.87266

int get_box(x,x_dot,theta,theta_dot)
float x,x_dot,theta,theta_dot;
{
  int box=0;

  if (x < -2.4 ||
      x > 2.4  ||
      theta < -twelve_degrees ||
      theta > twelve_degrees)          return(-1); /* to signal failure */

  if (x < -0.8)                box = 0;
  else if (x < 0.8)                box = 1;
  else                             box = 2;

  if (x_dot < -0.5)                ;
  else if (x_dot < 0.5)                box += 3;
  else                         box += 6;

  if (theta < -six_degrees)            ;
  else if (theta < -one_degree)        box += 9;
  else if (theta < 0)              box += 18;
  else if (theta < one_degree)         box += 27;
  else if (theta < six_degrees)        box += 36;
  else                         box += 45;

  if (theta_dot < -fifty_degrees)   ;
  else if (theta_dot < fifty_degrees)  box += 54;
  else                                 box += 108;

  return(box);
}
```

Comment: `1 << 31` will invoke *undefined behavior* by causing overflow if `int` is 32-bit long. Why not use `RAND_MAX`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kurt, it compiles, but with significant warnings. (compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -lm -o pole pole.c` to see just how many). One of the issues you are faced with is the *ancient* style function declarations., e.g.:

```
cart_pole(action, x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot)
int action;
float *x, *x_dot, *theta, *theta_dot;
```

instead of

```
void cart_pole (int action, float *x, float *x_dot, 
                float *theta, float *theta_dot)
```

As also pointed out, you will experience integer overflow with:

```
#define random                  ((float) rand() / (float)((1 << 31) - 1))
```

which you can remedy by using `unsigned` instead of `int` (remember the default type for all values is `int`), e.g.

```
#define random                  ((float) rand() / (float)((1U << 31) - 1))
```

Putting those pieces together and explicitly setting `int main (void)` and returning a value from `main`, you can compile without warning with the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define min(x, y)               ((x <= y) ? x : y)
#define max(x, y)               ((x >= y) ? x : y)
#define prob_push_right(s)      (1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-max(-50.0, min(s, 50.0)))))
#define random                  ((float) rand() / (float)((1U << 31) - 1))

#define N_BOXES     162     /* Number of disjoint boxes of state space. */
#define ALPHA       1000    /* Learning rate for action weights, w. */
#define BETA        0.5     /* Learning rate for critic weights, v. */
#define GAMMA       0.95    /* Discount factor for critic. */
#define LAMBDAw     0.9     /* Decay rate for w eligibility trace. */
#define LAMBDAv     0.8     /* Decay rate for v eligibility trace. */

#define MAX_FAILURES     100    /* Termination criterion. */
#define MAX_STEPS        100000

typedef float vector[N_BOXES];

void cart_pole (int action, float *x, float *x_dot,
                float *theta, float *theta_dot);
int get_box (float x, float x_dot, float theta, float theta_dot);

int main (void)
{
    float x,                  /* cart position, meters */
    x_dot,                    /* cart velocity */
    theta,                    /* pole angle, radians */
    theta_dot;                /* pole angular velocity */
    vector w,                 /* vector of action weights */
    v,                        /* vector of critic weights */
    e,                        /* vector of action weight eligibilities */
    xbar;                     /* vector of critic weight eligibilities */
    float p, oldp, rhat, r;
    int box, i, y, steps = 0, failures = 0, failed;

    printf ("Seed? ");
    scanf ("%d", &i);
    srand (i);

/*--- Initialize action and heuristic critic weights and traces. ---*/
    for (i = 0; i < N_BOXES; i++)
        w[i] = v[i] = xbar[i] = e[i] = 0.0;

/*--- Starting state is (0 0 0 0) ---*/
    x = x_dot = theta = theta_dot = 0.0;

/*--- Find box in state space containing start state ---*/
    box = get_box (x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot);

/*--- Iterate through the action-learn loop. ---*/
    while (steps++ < MAX_STEPS && failures < MAX_FAILURES) {
    /*--- Choose action randomly, biased by current weight. ---*/
        y = (random < prob_push_right (w[box]));

    /*--- Update traces. ---*/
        e[box] += (1.0 - LAMBDAw) * (y - 0.5);
        xbar[box] += (1.0 - LAMBDAv);

    /*--- Remember prediction of failure for current state ---*/
        oldp = v[box];

    /*--- Apply action to the simulated cart-pole ---*/
        cart_pole (y, &x, &x_dot, &theta, &theta_dot);

    /*--- Get box of state space containing the resulting state. ---*/
        box = get_box (x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot);

        if (box < 0) {
        /*--- Failure occurred. ---*/
            failed = 1;
            failures++;
            printf ("Trial %d was %d steps.\n", failures, steps);
            steps = 0;

        /*--- Reset state to (0 0 0 0).  Find the box. ---*/
            x = x_dot = theta = theta_dot = 0.0;
            box = get_box (x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot);

        /*--- Reinforcement upon failure is -1. Prediction of failure is 0. ---*/
            r = -1.0;
            p = 0.;
        } else {
        /*--- Not a failure. ---*/
            failed = 0;

        /*--- Reinforcement is 0. Prediction of failure given by v weight. ---*/
            r = 0;
            p = v[box];
        }

    /*--- Heuristic reinforcement is:   current reinforcement
            + gamma * new failure prediction - previous failure prediction ---*/
        rhat = r + GAMMA * p - oldp;

        for (i = 0; i < N_BOXES; i++) {
        /*--- Update all weights. ---*/
            w[i] += ALPHA * rhat * e[i];
            v[i] += BETA * rhat * xbar[i];
            if (v[i] < -1.0)
                v[i] = v[i];

            if (failed) {
            /*--- If failure, zero all traces. ---*/
                e[i] = 0.;
                xbar[i] = 0.;
            } else {
            /*--- Otherwise, update (decay) the traces. ---*/
                e[i] *= LAMBDAw;
                xbar[i] *= LAMBDAv;
            }
        }

    }
    if (failures == MAX_FAILURES)
        printf ("Pole not balanced. Stopping after %d failures.", failures);
    else
        printf ("Pole balanced successfully for at least %d steps\n", steps);

    return 0;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------
cart_pole:  Takes an action (0 or 1) and the current values of the
four state variables and updates their values by estimating the state
TAU seconds later.
----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*** Parameters for simulation ***/

#define GRAVITY 9.8
#define MASSCART 1.0
#define MASSPOLE 0.1
#define TOTAL_MASS (MASSPOLE + MASSCART)
#define LENGTH 0.5              /* actually half the pole's length */
#define POLEMASS_LENGTH (MASSPOLE * LENGTH)
#define FORCE_MAG 10.0
#define TAU 0.02                /* seconds between state updates */
#define FOURTHIRDS 1.3333333333333

void cart_pole (int action, float *x, float *x_dot,
                float *theta, float *theta_dot)
{
    float xacc, thetaacc, force, costheta, sintheta, temp;

    force = (action > 0) ? FORCE_MAG : -FORCE_MAG;
    costheta = cos (*theta);
    sintheta = sin (*theta);

    temp = (force + POLEMASS_LENGTH * *theta_dot * *theta_dot * sintheta)
        / TOTAL_MASS;

    thetaacc = (GRAVITY * sintheta - costheta * temp)
        / (LENGTH * (FOURTHIRDS - MASSPOLE * costheta * costheta
                    / TOTAL_MASS));

    xacc = temp - POLEMASS_LENGTH * thetaacc * costheta / TOTAL_MASS;

/*** Update the four state variables, using Euler's method. ***/

    *x += TAU * *x_dot;
    *x_dot += TAU * xacc;
    *theta += TAU * *theta_dot;
    *theta_dot += TAU * thetaacc;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------
get_box:  Given the current state, returns a number from 1 to 162
designating the region of the state space encompassing the current state.
Returns a value of -1 if a failure state is encountered.
----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#define one_degree 0.0174532    /* 2pi/360 */
#define six_degrees 0.1047192
#define twelve_degrees 0.2094384
#define fifty_degrees 0.87266

int get_box (float x, float x_dot, float theta, float theta_dot)
{
    int box = 0;

    if (x < -2.4 ||
        x > 2.4 || theta < -twelve_degrees || theta > twelve_degrees)
        return (-1);            /* to signal failure */

    if (x < -0.8)
        box = 0;
    else if (x < 0.8)
        box = 1;
    else
        box = 2;

    if (x_dot < -0.5);
    else if (x_dot < 0.5)
        box += 3;
    else
        box += 6;

    if (theta < -six_degrees);
    else if (theta < -one_degree)
        box += 9;
    else if (theta < 0)
        box += 18;
    else if (theta < one_degree)
        box += 27;
    else if (theta < six_degrees)
        box += 36;
    else
        box += 45;

    if (theta_dot < -fifty_degrees);
    else if (theta_dot < fifty_degrees)
        box += 54;
    else
        box += 108;

    return (box);
}
```

Running gives the published results. I know this doesn't solve all your issues, but hopefully it will help you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I've gone back a step and copy-pasted `pole.h` into the original `pole.c` only, without maintaining any previous modifications. The resulting program (shown below) compiles.

```
/* Parameters for reinforcement algorithm.  */

#define min(x, y)               ((x <= y) ? x : y)
#define max(x, y)           ((x >= y) ? x : y)
#define prob_push_right(s)      (1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-max(-50.0, min(s, 50.0)))))
#define random                  ((float) rand() / (float)((1 << 31) - 1))

#define N_BOXES         162         /* Number of disjoint boxes of state space. */
#define ALPHA       1000        /* Learning rate for action weights, w. */
#define BETA        0.5         /* Learning rate for critic weights, v. */
#define GAMMA       0.95        /* Discount factor for critic. */
#define LAMBDAw     0.9         /* Decay rate for w eligibility trace. */
#define LAMBDAv     0.8         /* Decay rate for v eligibility trace. */

#define MAX_FAILURES     300         /* Termination criterion. */
#define MAX_STEPS        100000

#define RUNS 1


/*** Parameters for simulation ***/

#define GRAVITY 9.8
#define MASSCART 1.0
#define MASSPOLE 0.1
#define TOTAL_MASS (MASSPOLE + MASSCART)
#define LENGTH 0.5        /* actually half the pole's length */
#define POLEMASS_LENGTH (MASSPOLE * LENGTH)
#define FORCE_MAG 10.0
#define TAU 0.02          /* seconds between state updates */
#define FOURTHIRDS 1.3333333333333

#include <math.h>
// #include "pole.h"


typedef float vector[N_BOXES];

main()
{
  int i,seed;

  printf("enter seed:");
  scanf("%d",&seed);
  srand(seed);

  for (i=0; i<RUNS; i++)
    run_trial(i);

}

run_trial(run)
int run;
{
  float x,          /* cart position, meters */
        x_dot,          /* cart velocity */
        theta,          /* pole angle, radians */
        theta_dot;      /* pole angular velocity */
  vector  w,            /* vector of action weights */
          v,            /* vector of critic weights */
          e,            /* vector of action weight eligibilities */
          xbar;         /* vector of critic weight eligibilities */
  float p, oldp, rhat, r;
  int tsteps=0,box, i,y, steps = 0, failures=0, failed;

  /*--- Initialize action and heuristic critic weights and traces. ---*/
  for (i = 0; i < N_BOXES; i++)
    w[i] = v[i] = xbar[i] = e[i] = 0.0;

  /*--- Starting state is (0 0 0 0) ---*/
  x = x_dot = theta = theta_dot = 0.0;

  /*--- Find box in state space containing start state ---*/
  box = get_box(x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot);

  /*--- Iterate through the action-learn loop. ---*/
  while (steps++ < MAX_STEPS && failures < MAX_FAILURES)
    {
      /*--- Choose action randomly, biased by current weight. ---*/
      y = (random < prob_push_right(w[box]));

      tsteps++;  /* total number of steps */

      /*--- Update traces. ---*/
      e[box] += (1.0 - LAMBDAw) * (y - 0.5);
      xbar[box] += (1.0 - LAMBDAv);

      /*--- Remember prediction of failure for current state ---*/
      oldp = v[box];

      /*--- Apply action to the simulated cart-pole ---*/
      cart_pole(y, &x, &x_dot, &theta, &theta_dot);

      /*--- Get box of state space containing the resulting state. ---*/
      box = get_box(x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot);

      if (box < 0)
    {
      /*--- Failure occurred. ---*/
      failed = 1;
      failures++;
      printf("Trial %d was %d steps.\n", failures, steps);
      steps = 0;

      /*--- Reset state to (0 0 0 0).  Find the box. ---*/
      x = x_dot = theta = theta_dot = 0.0;
      box = get_box(x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot);

      /*--- Reinforcement upon failure is -1. Prediction of failure is 0. ---*/
      r = -1.0;
      p = 0.;
    }
      else
    {
      /*--- Not a failure. ---*/
      failed = 0;

      /*--- Reinforcement is 0. Prediction of failure given by v weight. ---*/
      r = 0;
      p= v[box];
    }

      /*--- Heuristic reinforcement is:   current reinforcement
          + gamma * new failure prediction - previous failure prediction ---*/
      rhat = r + GAMMA * p - oldp;

      for (i = 0; i < N_BOXES; i++)
    {
      /*--- Update all weights. ---*/
      w[i] += ALPHA * rhat * e[i];
      v[i] += BETA * rhat * xbar[i];
      if (v[i] < -1.0)
        v[i] = v[i];

      if (failed)
        {
          /*--- If failure, zero all traces. ---*/
          e[i] = 0.;
          xbar[i] = 0.;
        }
      else
        {
          /*--- Otherwise, update (decay) the traces. ---*/
          e[i] *= LAMBDAw;
          xbar[i] *= LAMBDAv;
        }
    }

    }
  if (failures == MAX_FAILURES)
    printf("run:%d Pole not balanced. Stopping after %d trials and %d steps.",run,failures,tsteps);
  else
    printf("Run:%d Pole balanced successfully for at least %d steps after %d trials and %d steps\n", run,steps,failures,tsteps);
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------
   cart_pole:  Takes an action (0 or 1) and the current values of the
 four state variables and updates their values by estimating the state
 TAU seconds later.
----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

cart_pole(action, x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot)
int action;
float *x, *x_dot, *theta, *theta_dot;
{
    float xacc,thetaacc,force,costheta,sintheta,temp;

    force = (action>0)? FORCE_MAG : -FORCE_MAG;
    costheta = cos(*theta);
    sintheta = sin(*theta);

    temp = (force + POLEMASS_LENGTH * *theta_dot * *theta_dot * sintheta)
                 / TOTAL_MASS;

    thetaacc = (GRAVITY * sintheta - costheta* temp)
           / (LENGTH * (FOURTHIRDS - MASSPOLE * costheta * costheta
                                              / TOTAL_MASS));

    xacc  = temp - POLEMASS_LENGTH * thetaacc* costheta / TOTAL_MASS;

/*** Update the four state variables, using Euler's method. ***/

    *x  += TAU * *x_dot;
    *x_dot += TAU * xacc;
    *theta += TAU * *theta_dot;
    *theta_dot += TAU * thetaacc;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------
   get_box:  Given the current state, returns a number from 1 to 162
  designating the region of the state space encompassing the current state.
  Returns a value of -1 if a failure state is encountered.
----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#define one_degree 0.0174532    /* 2pi/360 */
#define six_degrees 0.1047192
#define twelve_degrees 0.2094384
#define fifty_degrees 0.87266

get_box(x,x_dot,theta,theta_dot)
float x,x_dot,theta,theta_dot;
{
  int box=0;

  if (x < -2.4 ||
      x > 2.4  ||
      theta < -twelve_degrees ||
      theta > twelve_degrees)          return(-1); /* to signal failure */

  if (x < -0.8)                box = 0;
  else if (x < 0.8)                box = 1;
  else                             box = 2;

  if (x_dot < -0.5)                ;
  else if (x_dot < 0.5)                box += 3;
  else                         box += 6;

  if (theta < -six_degrees)            ;
  else if (theta < -one_degree)        box += 9;
  else if (theta < 0)              box += 18;
  else if (theta < one_degree)         box += 27;
  else if (theta < six_degrees)        box += 36;
  else                         box += 45;

  if (theta_dot < -fifty_degrees)   ;
  else if (theta_dot < fifty_degrees)  box += 54;
  else                                 box += 108;

  return(box);
}
```